# AWS communication between two public EC2 instances in same VPC

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have created a VPC. And inside that vpc in same subnet there are two ec2 instances. There is a deployed application on the first one and on the second one there is installed mysql. I have set up the application to connect to the instance with the installed db but with no success. I will copy the security groups configuration and the db configuration.
How to make both of these two instance communicate and the application from the first instance start using the db on the second. Both of them have public ip and can ping each other.

DB connection

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://some_ip:3306/demo
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Security groups
There are two security groups and both of the are assign to every ec2 instance.

[image]

The added id is the ID of this group.

[image]

**EDIT1** - of the second security group
[image]

Comment: When two instances have public IPs, you still want them to access each other using their *private* IPs.  Confirm whether this is what you are doing, please.

Comment: I do not want to access each other with their private IPs. I am trying to connect them using the public IPs. Instancce1 has a deployed java app and instance2 has mysql DB and i am trying to consume that DB from the app.

Comment: Then you need to list the public IPs of the Java instance in the security group of the MySQL instance.  The security group identity is lost when you go out to the Internet and back, which is what happens when two instances communicate using public IPs.  You are also billed for the traffic going out and coming back in, so it isn't clear why you would want to use the public IPs.

Comment: You _really, really, really_ should be connecting via Private IP. This is better for security, billing and performance. You would need a very good reason to use the Public IP instead.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Both of the security groups which i show in my question are added to the application and db instances. What rules do i have to set.

Comment: @npn the security group of the database server needs to allow TCP 3306 from the public IP (not sg-xxx) of the other machine(s) accessing it, if that's how you're doing it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Question is edited. I have added rule for port 3306 but still do not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your security group you are not allowing port 3306 which the database needs to communicate over.

Install mysql-client on your app server you can use the cli to see if you can connect to the database MySQL server using:

```
mysql -h mysql://some_ip -u root
```

Comment: I`ve added 3306 port. But when i try to connect to the db as you show i have - Unknown MySQL server host.

Comment: @npn Can you connect via `mysql` from the **same instance** that is running the database, just to confirm that the database is running correctly? (Try doing it via both the Public IP and the Private IP.)